# How can the door of an Indesit IWDC 6105 be opened when the internal door lock has burned?

Tags: appliances, washing-machine

I have an Indesit IWDC 6105 washing machine ([link to manual](https://www.manualslib.com/manual/257444/Indesit-Washer-Dryer-Iwdc-6105.html)) and its internal door lock burned during the cycle, causing the machine to be unusable (at least perhaps until the lock is replaced). Image below:

[image]

Given that the machine has no apparent mechanism to manually release the locked door, and that the lock appears to be attached by two screws that are behind the door (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AxFJXCfgmlA&t=55s), how can the lock actually be removed?

I am keen also to remove clothing that is currently trapped inside before they get destroyed.

Answer (score 1):

At this point, since the part is plastic and the wires burnt to a crisp, I'd go in there with a screwdriver  and break the lock off the frame and see if that frees up the door.  It looks like you'll need part of the wiring harness along with the lock mechanism  to repair it.